# django registration test fails on test_get_version

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-registration

Also, what is this test for anyway?

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_version (registration.tests.RegistrationVersionInfoTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arnar/Documents/git/liveproject/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/tests/__init__.py", line 45, in test_get_version
    self.assertEqual(registration.get_version(), version_dict['expected'])
AssertionError: '1.0' != '1.0 pre-alpha'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 55 tests in 7.332s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the test is to check that the [`get_version`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration/__init__.py#cl-3) function in the `registration/__init.py` module works.

I had a quick look at the source code for `get_version` and the failing test (version 0.8), and it looks like a bug to me. There's a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/25/updated-expected-versions-for-unit-tests) about the issue on bitbucket.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I do think the question should have been expanded (something like "why is this built-in uni test failing")- the "what is this test for anyway" question looks ancillary to me (thus the "Also").

Comment: It is the latest version (0.8), installed using pip. django version is 1.4 and no, I haven't modified it.

Comment: @ArnarYngvason I've updated my answer. It looks like a bug to me.